# How do you auto-align method arguments in Swift using the colon?

Tags: xcode, swift

In Objective-C, method arguments are aligned based on their colon when adding a newline.

In Swift, this doesn't seem to be the case and I can't get it to work. How do I enable this for Swift?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find if there’s a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the IDE (Xcode) and there is, unfortunately, no option even as of Xcode 7.1. The only way to get Apple to prioritize this is to [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) against Xcode.